# About Quantum Algorithm: Matrix Products Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

How can I calculate matrix products by using a quantum circuit?
Or, is there any quantum algorithm that can be used to calculate matrix products? I'm trying to find some demo codes or essays with circuits.
I have tried to find a quantum algorithm to calculate classical matrix products, but I didn't find any available sources to do it. If anyone knows about it, please share it with me.

Comment: [Here's a paper going over a few.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01601)

Comment: Thank you for sharing